# Can I put plywood underlayment under Ditra/tile?

Tags: tile, subfloor, underlayment

I'm taking up hardwood floor in a bathroom and will be replacing with tile. The hardwood was put in over wood chipboard(?) subfloor with 1/8" plywood underlayment. In order not to have a huge height disparity between the wood floor l'm leaving and the new tile, can install a new 1/8 underlayment under the Ditra plan to put under the tile?

Pictured is the tile on top of the existing underlayment up against the wood floor that will remain.
[image: tile on top of underlayment]

Comment: The thickness of the sub floor is important to know.  Tile likes a very solid(inch plus) floor.  Tile does not bend, so if the floor moves under weight it will usually crack.  Extra wood to raise it up is okay.

Comment: @crip659 how do I check that depth? Home built in 2001 so I would guess it should be thick enough? Doesn't seem to flex under weight and it's only a 5ft x 5ft space.

Comment: The easy way is just drill a hole though it.  Most sub floors are only 3/4 inch or even 1/2 inch if saving money.  Most tiles are quite fragile.  They should come with installation instructions on what is needed.

Comment: Why the Ditra? Are you looking for a waterproof layer to protect the subfloor?

Comment: Planning to use it based on recommendations, but not specifically for water proofing. Only a half bath.

Comment: If the subfloor was put in with plans showing hardwood, there's no reason to expect it to be thick enough for tile. Chipboard is formally OSB (oriented strand board.)

Comment: Your floor sheathing isn't stiff enough, so the space filled by the Ditra would better be filled by something that adds stiffness. You should look at the "F" prefixed designs from the TCNA Handbook. You should not look on z-lib to find a downloadable copy. F146 looks somewhat thin, F175 looks somewhat thin, F147 looks pretty close to your current plan, etc.

Comment: @popham ok I've taken more measurements. The subfloor is 3/4" and the joists are 16" on center. Looking at the install instructions for Ditra, the minimum for my setup would be 5/8" subfloor, which I've already exceeded and would do moreso if put down a 1/8" (or even 1/4") plywood layer overtop of the existing subfloor. Am I missing something that makes my plan a bad one?

Comment: It's not "chipboard," i.e. particleboard is it? If it's actually OSB or plywood, then I stand corrected. I'm pretty sure that Schluter even warrantees their stuff if it's installed to spec. (Technically you could run afoul if your subfloor has seams that aren't tongue-groove.)

Comment: @popham I wonder if Ditra is being used to minimize the thickness of the overall section.  Ordinarily you'd use 1/4" CBU, but the Ditra is only 1/8".

Comment: @popham I think I'm getting my terms confused. I think it is OSB based on trying to figure out what things are actually called and reviewing images of different things. Also from look at the seams it appears they are tongue and groove, as there are slight gaps where the seams are, but there is material in the gap like you'd expect to see if the tongue was in the way. So the subfloor is 3/4" OSB, tongue and groove, 16" on center.

Comment: @TheGremlyn, from what little I see in your photo, it looks like plywood to me, which Schluter specifies as interchangeable with OSB. OSB is a bunch of 2" to 3" long by 1" to 2" wide by  thin chunks of wood that have been hydraulic pressed with glue into a solid sheets. Ultimately it sounds like you're in spec. Are you trying to get confirmation that you're in spec?

Comment: @TheGremlyn, I've been using Schluter's installation pdf.

Comment: @popham the picture has the plywood underlayment from the hardwood still in place. What's under that definitely looks like OSB. What I want to do is replace the existing underlayment that was under the hardwood with new plywood, and that would be under the Ditra. The Ditra alone doesn't look thick enough to not have a moderate different in height, and I'd like the floor heights to be as similar as possible.

Comment: @TheGremlyn, if you've accurately represented the OSB subfloor, then you're within Schluter's instructions. Looking at the Schluter installation pdf, they spec a minimum underlayment thickness of 3/8" and they have very specific detailing. You should follow that. EJ171 specifies a 1/4" gap around your perimeter if you're interested.

Comment: @popham I've read over the spec sheet a few times, but it doesn't directly address my question of whether it is ok to put a layer of plywood on top of my OSB before putting down the Ditra layer. The closest it gets to addressing it is that it is says "Therefore, DITRA can replace a second layer of plywood in most applications." That indicates that you could use it with a second layer of plywood, but how and with what specs isn't anywhere I can find. Is it enough to screw the second layer down to joists? Do I need to glue it too? Can I even use a 1/4" underlayment with DITRA?

Answer (score 0):

According to Schluter's Ditra Installation Handbook (linked from the downloads section of https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Membranes/Uncoupling-(DITRA)/Schluter%C2%AE-DITRA-&-DITRA-XL/p/DITRA), a Ditra underlayment needs minimum thickness of 3/8":

> Place underlayment panels (Exposure 1, plugged-face plywood or OSB of minimum 3/8" (10 mm) thickness) with long dimension perpendicular to floor joists....

The handbook goes on to provide precise details for fastening, gaps between sheets, and other minutiae. You should definitely take a look at the whole page worth of information.